# What is next: 2, 3, 5, 13, 89, 233, ...?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Based on what is shown, what is the next number in the sequence?

Comment: It's not really an original puzzle if you can google the title and get the answer.

Comment: If this is simply the OEIS sequence already mentioned in an answer, it's not so much a *puzzle* as it is a bit of math-themed trivia. See [Number-Sequence Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5712) and, in particular, **[this answer under it](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5720)**, for why this kind of thing is unlikely to fare well here.

Answer (score 4):

The next number is:

> 1597

Because this sequence is:

> A [Prime Fibonacci numbers (A005478)](https://oeis.org/A005478) sequence.